# Android Live Streaming issue in IP CAMERA example?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am new to android. I'm looking for live streaming from android mobile to remote server. I searched and tried lot of examples in internet. But mostly i have some issues in placing the codes in server side to get the live streaming from mobile. I worked on [IP CAMERA](https://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/) example and tested in ICS version in android. The camera starts recording but i can't see output in browser. The player shows the error of[image]

I cleared the errors and placed the raw folder in http server but i didn't got right output.

Thanks in advance and I want to know

1. Am i want to install any media servers or Is http server enough to get running ip camera example.
2. where to place the raw folder of the ip camera example in the server.
3. They specified libjingle, am i want to any extra step with ip camera.

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv javacv i have it working on Android device streaming live to a server , instead of your ipcamera example it gets complicated have tried that one before. https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera is a better example for an ip camera.